# How to call an executable from self-hosted asp.net-core application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, ipc, .net-core

Is it possible to run `.exe` file with parameters and receive back value from `asp.net-core` self-hosted application? If yes - how?

I tried putting `ConsoleApp1.exe` in the project root folder and calling `LaunchCommandLineApp` from Controller, but it didn't work: `exeProcess` properties where filled with errors

```
static void LaunchCommandLineApp()
{
    // For the example.
    const string ex1 = "C:\\";
    const string ex2 = "C:\\Dir";

    // Use ProcessStartInfo class.
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.FileName = "ConsoleApp1.exe";
    //startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.Arguments = "-f j -o \"" + ex1 + "\" -z 1.0 -s y " + ex2;

    try
    {
        // Start the process with the info we specified.
        // Call WaitForExit and then the using-statement will close.
        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log error.
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Which errors were pointed on exeProcess?

Comment: please see the edit

Comment: Do you actually need any of those properties? If not, why do you care about their errors?

Comment: because `ConsoleApp1.exe` wasn't really executed

Comment: i don't know if it has anything to do with the errors, just thought it might be important